# Why doesn't my regex match when I use a one-char-long character set?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match monetary values in Perl. Being in the UK, I'm going to start with only matching `£`s, and will later branch out to other currencies, so to signify this I put the `£` character in a character set. The code looks like this:

```
my $re = qr/ Spent \s+ [£] (?<amount> \d+) /x;
if ( $input =~ $re ) {
    print $+{amount};
}
```

And here's an example input file:

```
- Spent £6 on beer
- Spent £4 on sobriety pills
```

And yet if I run this file, it matches nothing! However, if I remove the `£` from its character set:

```
my $re = qr/ Spent \s+ £ (?<amount> \d+) /x;
```

**Now** the numbers get printed. Note that I removed the `[]` from the regex. Aren't character sets meant to match any of their enclosed values? What's even stranger is that if I replace the `£` character in both the regex and the input file with something in ASCII, such as `E`, it works fine even if it's enclosed in a character set.

Both the script and the input file are UTF-8, I'm on Perl 5.18.2, and the only module I'm importing is Moose.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nB2lL9/8

Comment: Yeah, I thought it *should* work. Is this a Perl issue, then?

Comment: i m not very sure.not well versed in perl but perl regex is fine ass you can see from demo. :)

Comment: You can also shorten your regex .

Answer (score 1):

What encoding do you use? UTF-8? Did you tell Perl you do so?

```
use utf8; # The source is in UTF-8.
```

Also, if $input is coming from a file, did you tell Perl what encoding it uses?

```
open my $HANDLE, '<:encoding(utf-8)', 'input.txt' or die $!;
```

Comment: I had `use utf8`, but I was using File::Slurp, which I just discovered I have to pass in an encoding to. If I add `binmode => ':utf8'` to the call, it matches! Yay. I'm not sure why the character class in the regex would change its behaviour, though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `£` with its unicode:

```
my $re = qr/ Spent \s+ [\u00A3] (?<amount> \d+) /x;
```